# Missing Assembly Reference And Method must have a return type?! MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

im working in mvc 4 and try to implement jquery file uploader.

but in my FileStatus class and UploadHandler give me several errors.

-namespace FileStatus cannot be found,

-Method FileStatus need a return type.

i have an example and have seen that the method FileStatus dont return anything,

i dont´t know what is going on..

can someone give a hand?

**FIleStatusCLASS**

```
public class FileStatus
    {
        public const string HandlerPath = "/Upload/";

        public string group { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
        public string progress { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
        public string delete_url { get; set; }
        public string delete_type { get; set; }
        public string error { get; set; }

        public FilesStatus() { }

        public FilesStatus(FileInfo fileInfo) { SetValues(fileInfo.Name, (int)fileInfo.Length, fileInfo.FullName); }

        public FilesStatus(string fileName, int fileLength, string fullPath) { SetValues(fileName, fileLength, fullPath); }

        private void SetValues(string fileName, int fileLength, string fullPath)
        {
            name = fileName;
            type = "image/png";
            size = fileLength;
            progress = "1.0";
            url = HandlerPath + "UploadHandler.ashx?f=" + fileName;
            delete_url = HandlerPath + "UploadHandler.ashx?f=" + fileName;
            delete_type = "DELETE";

            var ext = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);

            var fileSize = ConvertBytesToMegabytes(new FileInfo(fullPath).Length);
            if (fileSize > 3 || !IsImage(ext)) thumbnail_url = "/Content/img/generalFile.png";
            else thumbnail_url = @"data:image/png;base64," + EncodeFile(fullPath);
        }

        private bool IsImage(string ext)
        {
            return ext == ".gif" || ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png";
        }

        private string EncodeFile(string fileName)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName));
        }

        static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
        {
            return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
        }

    }
```

**UPLOADHANDLER**

```
public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        private readonly JavaScriptSerializer js;

        private string StorageRoot
        {
            get { return Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/")); } //Path should! always end with '/'
        }

        public UploadHandler()
        {
            js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            js.MaxJsonLength = 41943040;
        }

        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "private, no-cache");

            HandleMethod(context);
        }

        // Handle request based on method
        private void HandleMethod(HttpContext context)
        {
            switch (context.Request.HttpMethod)
            {
                case "HEAD":
                case "GET":
                    if (GivenFilename(context)) DeliverFile(context);
                    else ListCurrentFiles(context);
                    break;

                case "POST":
                case "PUT":
                    UploadFile(context);
                    break;

                case "DELETE":
                    DeleteFile(context);
                    break;

                case "OPTIONS":
                    ReturnOptions(context);
                    break;

                default:
                    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 405;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static void ReturnOptions(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.AddHeader("Allow", "DELETE,GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,OPTIONS");
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        }

        // Delete file from the server
        private void DeleteFile(HttpContext context)
        {
            var filePath = StorageRoot + context.Request["f"];
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }
        }

        // Upload file to the server
        private void UploadFile(HttpContext context)
        {
            var statuses = new List<FilesStatus>();
            var headers = context.Request.Headers;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headers["X-File-Name"]))
            {
                UploadWholeFile(context, statuses);
            }
            else
            {
                UploadPartialFile(headers["X-File-Name"], context, statuses);
            }

            WriteJsonIframeSafe(context, statuses);
        }

        // Upload partial file
        private void UploadPartialFile(string fileName, HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses)
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count != 1) throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Attempt to upload chunked file containing more than one fragment per request");
            var inputStream = context.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
            var fullName = StorageRoot + Path.GetFileName(fileName);

            using (var fs = new FileStream(fullName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024];

                var l = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                while (l > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, l);
                    l = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                }
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
            }
            statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(new FileInfo(fullName)));
        }

        // Upload entire file
        private void UploadWholeFile(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < context.Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = context.Request.Files[i];

                var fullPath = StorageRoot + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                file.SaveAs(fullPath);

                string fullName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                statuses.Add(new FilesStatus(fullName, file.ContentLength, fullPath));
            }
        }

        private void WriteJsonIframeSafe(HttpContext context, List<FilesStatus> statuses)
        {
            context.Response.AddHeader("Vary", "Accept");
            try
            {
                if (context.Request["HTTP_ACCEPT"].Contains("application/json"))
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                else
                    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            }
            catch
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            }

            var jsonObj = js.Serialize(statuses.ToArray());
            context.Response.Write(jsonObj);
        }

        private static bool GivenFilename(HttpContext context)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request["f"]);
        }

        private void DeliverFile(HttpContext context)
        {
            var filename = context.Request["f"];
            var filePath = StorageRoot + filename;

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                context.Response.ClearContent();
                context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
            }
            else
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }

        private void ListCurrentFiles(HttpContext context)
        {
            var files =
                new DirectoryInfo(StorageRoot)
                    .GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                    .Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
                    .Select(f => new FilesStatus(f))
                    .ToArray();

            string jsonObj = js.Serialize(files);
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"files.json\"");
            context.Response.Write(jsonObj);
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        }
    }
```

For UploadHandler i use this:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

and for fileclass this:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

i know its a lot of code and sorry for that but i think its better to show you all the code.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What does your `namespace` look like for both of the classes..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring a class called `FileStatus`:

```
public class FileStatus
```

... but here you're trying to declare a constructor for `FilesStatus`:

```
public FilesStatus(FileInfo fileInfo)
```

(And the other constructors.)

Basically, your class name and the name specified in the constructor don't match, and they need to.

Comment: Ooops.. you are right... thanks a lot.. i forget one character.. Thank you very much.. Dont have seen this